# Autoconversion of data types in python in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, schema

I have a DF which has the following Schema :

1. o_orderkey  ---        int32
2. o_custkey   ---        int32
3. o_orderstatus ---      object
4. o_totalprice  ---      object
5. o_orderdate  ---       object
6. o_orderpriority ---    object
7. o_clerk         ---    object
8. o_shippriority  ---    int32
9. o_comment       ---    object

Here the total price is actually a float(Decimals) and the order date is date time.
But on using **df.convert_dtypes** or **df.infer_objects**, its not automatically convering them into float/int and  date time.

Is there any way to automatically read and convert the column data type into the correct one? For example in case we do not know the schema of such a data frame beforehand, how would we read and convert the data type to the correct one, without using a regex method to go through every object in the DF.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas tries to use the right datatype when read the data. However, if, for example, the `totalprice` column has string, it doesn't make sense for you to convert it to float. You also cannot force pandas to convert it to float, it will just report errors, which is the correct behaviour!

You have to use regex to clean up the string, then you can safely convert the column to float.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! But the totalprice column does not have any strings at all. It was originally a parquet file and the data type was decimal. When I converted the file to a DF, the data type became string for the totalprice column and it doesnt change on using .convert or .infer_objects.

Comment: I remember I had weird issues with parquet file data types as well. If you try csv, does the same issue still exist?

Comment: Basically convering the parquet to a df the same issue occurs. I never converted into CSV cause eventually I need to convert it into a .hyper format.